# Vuex cannot read property after refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

I have an `Navbar` component when I use in him values from Vuex store. Before enter to each of the route i run dispatch from vuex like here:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   //...
   store.dispatch("updateUserData"); 
   next();
});
```

my store:

```
const actions = {
  updateUserData({ commit }) {
    UserService.getUserData().then(
      (response) => {
        commit("updateUserState", response.data);
      },
      (error) => {}
    )
  },
}

const mutations = {
  updateUserState: function(state, user) {
    state.user = user;
  },
}

const getters = {
  getUser: (state) => {
    return state.user;
  }
}
```

additionally in my `Navbar` component i have this:

```
  computed: {
    currentUser() {
      return this.$store.getters.getUser;
    }
  },
```

and use this value like here:

```
<p style="border-left: 1px solid black" class="navIcon pl-4 py-1">
   {{ currentUser.firstName }} {{ currentUser.lastName }}
</p>
```

and now is problem, when I open the page where this `navbar` is used, my console and component works good, everything is ok and I have correctly rendering of the view, but after refresh the page, I have still correct data on the view but my console throw me this error:

```
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null"

found in

---> <Navbar> at src/layouts/Navbar.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.esm.js?a026:628
vue.esm.js?a026:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null
```

can someone tell me what is wrong here? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

What it looks to me is that your action is async, and the data might not be available to getter when your component renders.

You can try turning your action into asyn one, that returns a promise, and wait for it to resolve in `beforeEach` before calling `next`.

Try debugging you app after refresh. Look at vue store, log the value of the current user in component `mount` etc...

Comment: can you show an example of using async here?